# How to automatically maximize a pylab plot window in python?

Tags: python, window, resize, matplotlib

In python (under Ubuntu Linux), I'm using pylab to make plots.

When I call:

```
pylab.savefig(filename)
```

It saves the figure at the current screen resolution. The looks terrible if I have lots of subplots, so I usually have to manually maximize the window before I call 'savefig'.

Examples:

-- [Without maximizing the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PKTr.png)

-- [With window maximized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcN7V.png)

Is there some way to automatically maximize a pylab window?

*(I saw someone had posted a solution for Windows using win32gui, but I'm in Linux)*

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can change resolution this way:

```
pylab.savefig('new.png', dpi = 500)
```

Comment: That's useful to know, but it doesn't quite solve the problem. I'm going to add some image examples to my question